# confirming solution to the series $\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+3)^3}$ with ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to confirm my solution to this series using the ratio test correct, I tested to show the series is divergent.

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+3)^3}$$

Using the ratio test, then simplifying in stages:

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+1+1)}{(n+1+3)^3}\frac{(n+3)^3}{n(n+1)}$$

$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)^3}{(n+4)^3n(n+1)}$$

$$\frac{(n+2)(n+3)^3}{(n+4)^2(n+4)n}$$

$$\frac{(n+3)^3}{(n+4)^22n}$$

The concluding remark:

$$\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+3)^3}{(n+4)^2n}$$

Hence the series is divergent, unless I went wrong somewhere?

Comment: This is hard to follow.  First of all, are you speaking about $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {n(n+1)}{(n+3)^3}$ or something close to that?  Something else?  Secondly, what does it mean to say that one fraction implies another?  And what do you conclude from writing the limit at the end?

Comment: Your usage of implication arrows unfortunately make no sense.

Comment: To the underlying question, for large $n$ the numerator grows like $n^2$ while the denominator grows like $n^3$, so the expression approaches $\frac 1n$.  That should be enough.

Comment: The ratio test will be inconclusive for this series (the ratios of consecutive terms tend to $1$).

Comment: @RobArthan Is there a proof to this comment? I'd like to understand this through equations.

Comment: Like Lulu says the terms are asymptotic to $1/n$, so the ratios are asymptotic to $n/(n+1)$ which is asymptotic to $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the vein of @lulu 's comment, the fast way uses *asymptotic equivalence*: as a polynomial is equivalent to its leading term, we have
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+3)^3}\sim_\infty\frac{n^2}{n^3}=\frac 1n,$$
which is a divergent series.

Answer (score 3):

Without using asymptotic equivalence, an easy way is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac{n}{n+3}\times\dfrac{n+1}{n+3}\times\dfrac{1}{n+3}\right)\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\dfrac14\times\dfrac24\times\dfrac{1}{n+3}\right)=\infty
\end{equation}

Another alternative solution is
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n(n+1)}{(n+3)^3}\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n^2}{(n+3n)^3}=\infty
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Ratio test is not effective because
$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{(n+2) (n+3)^3}{n (n+4)^3}=1$$
You can use comparison test as
$$\frac{n (n+1)}{(n+3)^3}\sim \frac1n ;\text{ as }n\to\infty$$
and $\sum\frac1n $ diverges